# WebGL - getAttribLocation: no object , Shader issue

Tags: webgl, shader

I have the following issue with my WebGl code.

```
ERROR:

WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: getAttribLocation: no object or object deleted
```

My draw function:

```
function drawScene () {
    vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(glProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trianglesVerticeBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

My Shaders, are loaded, created and attached to the program with no issues. I linked and used the program. But still cannot find my mistake.

Vertex:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
void main(void) {
gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment:

```
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle? it is hard to know without the rest of the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kf8ZD/
The shaders are missing. You find the rest there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to draw the scene before `initShaders()` has finished creating the `glProgram`. Remember that you are downloading the shader files asynchronously, so your `drawScene()` function is being runned before your shaders have even been downloaded.

To fix this change the following line in your `loadFile()` function so that it preforms a synchronous request like so:

```
request.open('GET', url, false);
```

[Here](http://antonpantev.com/so-related/getAttribLocation/) is a link to a working version of your code.